# Python and sqlite3 throwing an error: sqlite3.OperationalError: near "s": syntax error

Tags: python, sqlite, web-scraping

I'm trying to use Python and BeautifulSoup to scrape some web info, iterate through it and then insert some pieces into a sqlite3 DB. But I keep coming up with this error:

File "/Users/Chris/Desktop/BS4/TBTfile.py", line 103, in TBTscrape
    c.execute(item)
sqlite3.OperationalError: near "s": syntax error

This same code works fine on a very similar scraper and does not throw these errors. Here's the portion of it:

```
listicle.append("INSERT INTO headlines (heds, url, image_loc, time, source) VALUES ('" + TBTheadline + "', '" + TBTurl + "', '" + imageName + "', '" + TBTpostDate + "', '" + source + "')")

    else:
        print "TBT item already in database"

print listicle

for item in listicle:
    c.execute(item)
    conn.commit()
    row = c.fetchall()
    print "This has been inserted succcessfully: ", item
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are concatenating the collected data into your SQL statements. *Never* do that, it is the [mother of all anti-patterns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). Aside from the problems you are seeing (probably due to a ' or similar character in the scraped HTML), you have a gaping security hole in your code (may or may not matter in your case).

Anyway, `sqlite3` has a nice way of doing exactly what you want: [`executemany`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.Cursor.executemany). In your case

```py
listicle.append((TBTheadline,TBTurl,imageName,TBTpostDate,source))

conn.executemany("INSERT INTO headlines (heds, url, image_loc, time, source) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)", listicle)
```

Comment: Wow, that's so much easier. I hadn't come across that yet. Beautiful, thanks!